# Why does replacing innerHTML get slower as innerHTML get's larger?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a div that is *not* contentEditable. I capture keystrokes, insert the associated char into a string in memory, and then call a render() function that replaces the innerHTML of the div with the current string.

My question is, why does this loop get slower and slower as the innerHTML get's larger? All I'm doing is overwriting the innerHTML of the div with a straight string. Shouldn't this be constant time?

```
dojo.byId('thisFrame').innerHTML = this.value.string;
```

I don't understand how this is dependent on the size of the string at all. It slows down when the string's length gets over about 200 characters, and slows down drastically from there on out.

Comment: If that was all the code then it would be instant even with 200 000 characters.. show more.

Comment: Try writing the `textContent` instead of the `innerHTML` property... If the string is not HTML source code, you shouldn't be using `innerHTML`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dojo.byId('thisFrame')
```

is a DOM element.  Setting the `innerHTML` property of a DOm element is not constant time because it causes a side effect which does not take constant time.

Specifically, assigning to `myHTMLElement.innerHTML` causes the browser to parse the string with its HTML parser and rewrite a chunk of the DOM.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#innerhtml0

> On setting, [innerHTML] replaces the node's children with new nodes that result from parsing the given value.

Parsing HTML is at least linear in the amount of HTML, and replacing the DOM is at least linear in both the number of nodes removed and the number of nodes added.

Comment: This makes sense. The string I'm using to replace the innerHTML looks like: <span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span>, with each new char being another span. So I guess replacing the innerHTML each time results in another parse of the HTML. Thanks for the info. Any suggestions on how I can do this any faster?

Comment: Perhaps only adding the new nodes to the innerHTML rather than replacing it in its entirety?

Comment: @user1022241, Yes.  Creating only the nodes you need is a good idea.  Everytime you have another `<span>x</span>` you are creating two nodes: an element and a text node.  I once wrote a calendar UI in HTML that was prohibitively slow (on IE 6) using table cells since that required O(nColumns * nRows) elements, but by using positioned DIVs, I got it down to O(nEvents) which was much more manageable.

Comment: If I do a div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.substr(0,10)+'<span>x</span'+div.innerHTML.substr(10,20) , isn't that the same thing as replacing the entirety of the innerHTML? I'm confused on how I'd just go about creating _only_ the new node and adding it to the current innerHTML.

Comment: @user1022241, If you have to create nodes via `innerHTML`, then you can always create an empty DIV, set its `innerHTML`, and then append its children to the original.

Comment: I notice now that using the DOM method insertBefore( ) still slows down _drastically_ based on the amount of innerHTML in the target node. Odd since this isn't replacing or re-rendering any of the innerHTML of that targetNode.

Answer (score 3):

The html you set using innerhtml must be parsed by the browser in order to get the DOM elements that make up the browsers internal representation of the div. This takes more time for a longer string with a greater number of elements.